# SQL Server - Converting date in "20140410" format to 04/10/2014 format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a server that outputs the date in the following format `YEARMONTHDAY`

Example `20140410`.

Question is how to I convert it to be as `MONTH/DAY/YEAR`, example `04/10/2014`

Thanks!

David

Comment: What version of sql server?  Is that date an int, varchar?  Why aren't you storing the date as an actual date?

Comment: It's usually far better to keep your data in appropriate data types (such as `datetime`) for as long as possible and only deal with *any* formatting immediately before its presented to the user. This is usually in a completely different layer than the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @theDate varchar(8)
set @theDate = '20140410'

select convert(varchar(10),cast(@theDate as date),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
declare @dt CHAR(8) = '20140131'
select @dt, CONVERT(DATE,@dt) as newDt
```

Here is a link on the CONVERT function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx and one on date types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 different versions, one version for if all values are valid YYYYMMDD format, and one that will still work with invalid dates (but will return null for invalids).

```
DECLARE @tblTest TABLE (id int not null identity, myDate int not null)

INSERT INTO @tblTest(myDate)
VALUES(20140308),(20140410)
;
--QUERY 1: if all values in your table are valid dates, then you can use this
SELECT t.id, t.myDate
    , myDateFormatted = CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t.myDate)),101)
FROM @tblTest t

--NOW INSERT SOME INVALID DATES AS WELL
INSERT INTO @tblTest(myDate)
VALUES(20140132),(48)
;

--NOW IF THERE ARE INVALID DATE, THEN USING QUERY 1 WOULD CAUSE AN ERROR: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
--QUERY 2: if there are ANY invalid values in your table, then you can use this
SELECT t.id, t.myDate
    , myDateFormatted = 
        CASE
            WHEN ISDATE(t.mydate) = 1 and len(t.myDate) = 8
            THEN CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t.myDate)),101)
            ELSE NULL --THIS IS AN INVALID DATE
        END
FROM @tblTest t
;
```